# How to enable graphics card XFX ATI RADEON HD 4350

Tags: 10.10, drivers, compiz, graphics, ati

I need to enable the 3D effects in the graphics card under Ubuntu 10.10 OS

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the proprietary drivers ?
Go to System --> Administration --> Aditional drivers and press "Enable".
After installation is complete, restart your computer.
Then after you login right click on your desktop --> Change Desktop Background --> Visual effects and select Extra.

Comment: For extra functionality and more tweaks you can also install "simple compiz manager". Search it in Ubuntu Software center. This will add an extra option in the Visual effects where you can customize the effects.

Comment: To tweak the settings of your Card you can use the ATI Catalyst Control Centre located in the preferences section of the system menu.

Comment: Just a note. The open source ATI driver also supports 3D visual effects. I have determined from my own experimentation that the open source ATI driver works much better than the proprietary driver, especially when viewing videos (DVD and .mkv files).

Answer (score 0):

I can concur that the open source drives work far better for 3d and 2d visual effects. The proprietary drivers add lots of artefacts, especially in 2D.